# Apply filter to value returned within a table wizard report (Reportbuilder

Tags: reporting-services, reportbuilder

looking for help or thoughts, Reportbuilder - I have a count value that has been generated from a count of a text field. Matrix report, count of PurOrd and count of PurIn. The report displays a numeric value rather than the actual text/word.  I’m struggling to find or workout the expression required to use the count value to return whether “Yes” or “No”.  If PurOrd (count value) = PurIn (count value) then “Yes” Else “No”.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without more info, like where in the matrix this will appear and what your current count expressions look like I can't give an exact answer so you will have to adjust this to suit.

Basically you can just use an `IIF()` statement to compare you two current expressions, something like...

```
=IIF(Count(Fields!PurOrd.Value) = Count(Fields!PurInv.Value), "Yes", "No")
```

If this does not help, EDIT your question and add all relevant info such as screen shots o the report design, current expression being used etc.

Comment: Thanks Alan, report looking good, however is it possible to add a filter to only display “No” within the expression?

Comment: Could this be added to the dataset in some way?

Comment: You probably need to ask a new question and show a sample of your data and the expected outcome. Typically it's much easier to do all this work in the dataset query.

Comment: If this answered your initial question, can you please mark the answer as accepted. That's the check mark below the vote up/down buttons